# login with facebook error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing web app which has facebook login also.I'm using facebook login 2 times in separate pages with same appID why because if the user use our login then to fetch his/her fb friendlist asking the user to do fb login there. I'm getting fb.init has already been called error in 1 page. I have tried all the solutions given in stack overflow. still am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [`FB.getLoginStatus()` function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) instead of initializing the SDK again -

> FB.getLoginStatus allows you to determine if a user is logged in to Facebook and has authenticated your app. There are three possible states for a user:
>
> - the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your application (connected)
> - the user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application (not_authorized)
> - the user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)

These three options **along with whatever mechanism you use** to authenticate users into your system should cover all the scenarios regarding authentication with Facebook.

To check the users current status, you can use some code similar to this -

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // logged in and authenticated 
    var fbid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // logged but not authorized
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok... so if you already know that the user is logged in, why call `FB.login()` a second time?

Comment: if the user is not logged in through fb(instead user login with our own login) but user wants to see his fb friends. I have to ask him to login right?